# Linux fgrep how to extract “only_words_in_my_language” from a big “MIXED_WORDS” file?

Tags: linux, grep

I want something to extract "only_words_in_my_language(900kb)" from a big "MIXED_WORDS(160mb)" file and for that i used the syntax bellow but with poor results:

```
fgrep -w -f "only_words_in_my_language.txt" "MIXED_WORDS_from_all_over_the_world" > extracted_word_of_my_country_only.txt
```

That's why i'm thinking mmmm.. to ''MATCH'' the entire WORD,for better results
For example this is a WORD in my language:

Maimuta - 7 letters lenght,if i match the entire word the results could be:

```
maimuta@123
maimuta2016!
Maimuta01!
maimuta@123456
```

if i match 6 letter the res. could be:

```
maimut
maimutoi1
Maimutareala01!
```

So my question is how to do that??how to match the entire word 
A regex or something for linux please
thank you
Godluck to all!!

i tried this but,dnes't work:

> fgrep -iowf "my_lang_dict.txt" "mixed_words" >
>   my_lang_unique-words.txt

### My lang.dict.txt(900kb) and mixed_file(64 mb),grep says: Memory Exhausted

Imagine ur bulgarian,russian and you want to extract ''only'' the words that are in the language of your country from a big mixed words all over the wordl text file.How u would do that?u need a ''ur country'' dictionary right?and then compare all the words from ur country dictionary with the mixed one and i think best results are.... when u match the entire word!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, you don't have enough memory. The system is building up a regular expression to match all the words in your 900KB file. The size of the mixed_word file doesn't matter. The error message might be misleading in that it might be that it really means `regular expression too complicated`.

You should be able to break your lang.dict.txt into smaller chunks. You can use the unix command `split` to do this.